# Can't access parent variables from prototype function

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I have a class in JavaScript which goes roughly as follows:

```
function StateManager () {
  this.storeDir = { read: (a, b) => { return false } }
  this.state = this.storeDir.read('./state.json', 'json') || { state: 'new' }
}

StateManager.prototype.update = () => {
  console.log(this.state.state)
}

module.exports = new StateManager()
```

Assuming this is a file called "StateManager.js", and we have another file in the same folder, I should be able to call it as follows:

```
let StateManager = require('./StateManager')

console.log(StateManager)
StateManager.update()
```

And I expect to see the `StateManager` object followed by the current state, which because we're using a dummy function will always be "new".  However, for some unknown reason, `this` within `.update()` is an empty object and hence `this.state.state` errors out.  `StateManager` appears to contain a popular `StateManager` object, however, so I can't understand why this is so.  Is there a way I can access `this.state` within the `StateManager.prototype.update` function?

Comment: Big arrow notation `() => {}` does not set `this` within the function definition.

Comment: @J.Titus to be precise, it preserves the context of the parent function.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I'll chime in and add a reference to an [explanation](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/)

Comment: Notice that you never should use classes when you intend to export an instance. Just use an object literal instead.